interpretation of a statement in the specifications
In one of the embodiments in the specifications, a sentence reads "The order of input of the colors is immaterial". However, immediately after this sentence the specification goes on to describe an optional modification that restricts the possible values a color can be inputted based the input of another color. For example, if "Color A is inputted to be red, then Color B can now only be inputted to be either green or blue".
Does this optional modification contradict the general statement that "The order of input of the colors is immaterial"?
What is actually intended to mean by this statement is that "The colors can be inputted in any order".
If it comes up either in examination or litigation, can the inventor insists that "The order of input of the colors is immaterial" is interpreted to mean "The colors can be inputted in any order"?

From the snippets of specification shown so far, I don't see that there is inherently any contradiction. The colors can be input in any order, yet it is possible to impose the condition that the next input color should be different from any previously input color. E.g., one could input 3 color slots from left to right as red, green, blue or from right to left as blue, green, red. But one could not input from left to right as blue, green, blue, for example. In other words, color A and color B can refer to the colors in input order.

But the literal statement that is written is "The order of input of the colors is immaterial". Does being immaterial mean that the order of input should have no effect or consequences? But in the optional modification, it does have an effect on the input of later colorrs.

_Bear: Say we have color slots 1, 2, 3. We can input Color A into slot 2 and color B into slot 1 and color C into slot 3, for example. And we can impose that Color A != Color B != Color C. But the order is still "immaterial" as we can also input in the order Color C into slot 3 and Color B into slot 1 and Color A into slot 2.
